# Correct verb conjugations?

Tags: verbos

Are these verbs conjugated correctly?

[image: ?]

our teacher just said we had to choose the right verb and the right form. What should I do... Because I don't think its correct right now

[image]

Comment: I agree with @gustavson, but note that you did conjugate for the first person singular very nicely.  Also note, exercises 2 and 3 sort of work the way you did them; and for me, exercise 5 doesn't really make sense.  I can't think of any country where people have *la cena* at some other time of day besides the evening.

Comment: It looks like you only had to choose between "se practica" and "se practican," etc. What do you think about #4?  Would that be singular or plural, do you think?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are expected to use impersonal or passive verbs with "se" in those sentences:

1. El snowboard **se practica** con una tabla.
2. En la tele **se ven** muchos partidos de tenis.
3. En este festival de música **se escucha** mucha música nueva.
4. En los Juegos Olímpicos **se baten** muchos récords. (More idiomatic than "se hacen")
5. En España **se cena** por la noche.